# Different definitions of Pearson residuals (Logistic Regression)

Tags: logistic, residuals

I needed help from friends about Pearson residuals in Logistic Regression:

a) The Pearson residual is the difference between the observed and estimated probabilities divided by the binomial standard deviation of the estimated probability. Therefore standardizing the residuals.

[image]

From Menard, Scott (2002). Applied logistic regression analysis, 2nd Edition. Thousand Oaks, CA: Sage Publications. Series: Quantitative Applications in the Social Sciences, No. 106. First ed., 1995. See Chapter 4.4

But

b) Pearson residuals are given by:

[image]

From Kutner (2013). Applied Linear Statistical Models.1 McGraw Hill India, 5th edition. See page 591

In my understanding the two formulas are different.

Comment: What is the formula given in (a)? It sounds like these are the same formulas. Possibly in (a) it is referring to a binomial case while in (b) it is Bernoulli, in which case (b) is a special case of (a).

Comment: @user0, I included the formula in the first example. Thanks

Comment: The first definition seems odd because we cannot observe $P(Y_i=1)$.  We can observe the proportion of Ys that are 1, so maybe that’s what’s meant by $P(Y_i=1)$.

Answer (score 4):

My library has the first book.  The notation isn't all that clear even given the book, but it appears to be $P(Y_j=1)$ for the empirical proportion of 1s in case j and $\hat P(Y_j=1)$ for the fitted probability from the model.

For binary (Bernoulli) data, $P(Y_j=1)$ is just $Y_j$, but for Binomial data $P(Y_j=1)$ will be number of successes/number of trials for that covariate pattern.

So, the two formulas are the same for binary data; the first formula is more general.